# Group and then sort data items in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to group some items in a kendo grid and then sort them in descending/ascending order post that. I understand that we can use the custom compare function here but I am not quite able to figure out the entire logic set. I have created a dojo with a sample code for the same [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/iDUzA)

Here in the example I am trying to sort such that I see the sorted girls first and then followed by the sorted males in the datasource list. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated your dojo with a simple fix for you.http://dojo.telerik.com/iDUzA/3

Comment: @DavidShorthose: Thanks for your answer. But the solution that I was looking for was a bit different. I wanted the girls to be always sorted first even after the sort on the column is clicked. The ascending and descending order follows post among the groups. If you notice in your dojo the sort gets screwed up after the first column click

Comment: if you want the sort on the initial load then present the data how you intend. As a user if I click name then I expect them to be order in alphabetical order rather than grouping by female then male then name. If you want this kind of sorting then maybe setting the grid up to pre-group like this update: http://dojo.telerik.com/iDUzA/4

Comment: I have already taken care of the sorting at the initial load by sorting the data before sending it across. I am now looking for only the sort when it is triggered by clicking on the grid column. Well at least on the UI I do not want the grids to be split like we do when we group them so I was looking for manipulating the code inside the compare handler. Moreover the sort does not work as expected as well when grouped. It takes 2 clicks on the column to sort the data in each group. You can notice this behaviour in your last example as well.

Comment: When you say clicking on the grid column are you talking about the header or an actual cell (if it is a cell why would you want the column to resort itself? With this "complex" sorting process then I would probably suggest using server side sorting for this rather client side unless you are presenting back your entire data set to the client? I may be just missing the point to your problem so apologies if I have been going about this completely wrong.

Comment: @DavidShorthose: Well I meant the column header and not the column cell. Sorry about the misunderstanding

Comment: is this more what you are after? http://dojo.telerik.com/iDUzA/6 it should hopefully give you a good starting point

Comment: Yea this looks like a pretty good starting point. I will try to develop on this.